# What is the average of rolling two dice and only taking the value of the higher dice roll?

Tags: probability, average, dice

What is the average result of rolling two dice, and only taking the value of the higher dice roll?

To make sure the situation I am asking about is clear, here is an example: 
I roll two dice and one comes up as a four and the other a six, the result would just be six.

Would the average dice roll be the same or higher than just rolling one dice?

Comment: With regard to your final question: what does your intuition tell you?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The number of ways to roll a number $x$ under your definition would be $2(x-1) + 1$.

Therefore the expected value would be
$$E[X] = \sum_{x=1}^6\frac{2(x-1)+1}{36}x = \frac{1}{36}\sum_{x=1}^6(2x^2 - x) = \frac{161}{36} \approx 4.47$$
So the average is considerably higher than the average of a single die, being $3.5$.

Comment: Where did $2(x - 1) + 1$ come from? (Answers below give explanations, but I'm wondering where you got it, since it seems to have come out of thin air.)

Comment: @AndreyM.Mishchenko To roll an $x$ with this scheme, you either (i) roll an $x$ with die 1, and a number less than $x$ with die 2, or (ii) roll an $x$ with die 2, and a number less than $x$ with die 1, or (iii) roll an $x$ with both dies. The possibilities for (i) and (ii) are $x-1$, so the total is $2(x-1)+1$.

Comment: Cool, makes sense. I asked because I think that's fundamentally the hard part of the problem, not the summation that follows it.

Answer (score 20):

For $k=1,\dots,6$ there are $k^2$ ways to get two numbers less than or equal to $k$. To get two numbers whose maximum is $k$ I must get two numbers that are less than or equal to $k$, but **not** two numbers that are less than or equal to $k-1$, so there are $k^2-(k-1)^2=k^2-(k^2-2k+1)=2k-1$ ways to get two numbers whose maximum is $k$. Thus, the probability of getting a maximum of $k$ is

$$\frac{2k-1}{36}\;,$$

and the expected value of the maximum is

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^6k\cdot\frac{2k-1}{36}&=\frac1{36}\sum_{k=1}^6\left(2k^2-k\right)\\
&=\frac1{18}\sum_{k=1}^6k^2-\frac1{36}\sum_{k=1}^6k\\
&=\frac{6\cdot7\cdot13}{18\cdot6}-\frac{6\cdot7}{36\cdot2}\\
&=\frac{91}{18}-\frac{21}{36}\\
&=\frac{161}{36}\\
&=4.47\overline{2}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Of course this is larger than the expected value of $\frac72=3.5$ for a single roll of a die: picking the maximum of the two numbers can be expected to bias the result upwards.

Comment: @Matthew: Thanks for catching the typo.

Answer (score 20):

I'll have a go and answer this the maths-lite way (though there are a number of answers with more mathematic rigor and .. dare I say it vigor posted here already).  The black dice represent the dice rolled, the white dice represent the max of the two dice in the respective row, column.

[image: Dice Results...]

Note that there is:

- 1 result with a face value 1
- 3 results with a face value 2,
- 5 results with a face value 3,
- 7 results with a face value 4,
- 9 results with a face value 5, and
- 11 results with a face value 6

The Average is defined to be:
$$\text{Average} = \frac{\text{Sum of the Results}}{\text{Total number of Results}}$$

The Sum of the Results is:
$$\begin{eqnarray} 
\text{Sum} &=& (1 \times 1) + (3 \times 2) + (5 \times 3) + (7 \times 4) + (9 \times 5) + (11 \times 6)     \nonumber \\
           &=& 1 + 6 + 15 + 28 + 45 + 66 \nonumber \\
           &=& 161    \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}$$

The Total number of Results is: $ 6 \times 6 = 36$

So the Average is:
$$\text{Average} = \frac{161}{36} \approx 4.472$$

Comment: This is awesome.

Answer (score 16):

This is very much delayed, but consider the case with an $n$-sided die.  As has already been observed, the expected value of the maximum of two $n$-sided die is

$${1 \over n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n (2k^2-k)$$

and we can write out this sum explicitly.  In particular, we can expand to get

$${1 \over n^2} \left( \left( 2 \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 \right) - \sum_{k=1}^n k \right)$$
and recalling the formulas for those sums, this is

$$ {1 \over n^2} \left( {2n(n+1)(2n+1) \over 6} - {n(n+1) \over 2} \right) $$

or after some rearrangement

$$ {(n+1)(4n-1) \over 6n}. $$

In particular this is approximately $2n/3$.  This could have been guessed if you know that the expectation of the maximum of two uniform random variables on $[0, 1]$ has the beta distribution $B(2,1)$, which has mean $2/3$.

Comment: Just posting to say I've visited this exact same question a couple times over the last two years and even though this isn't the accepted answer I find it far more useful.

Comment: 2 1/2 years later I'm still coming back to this answer

Comment: End of 2022 and still coming back to this answer <3

Comment: I agree, this is the best asnwer. Getting rid of the sum-operators is so good! Now we can quickly go through all dice D4, D6, ..., D20 (or impossible dice like a D3) and find that, astonishingly: The difference to the "regular" expected value scales ALMOST linearly with the number of dice-faces! Something beautiful happens if we take this formula, subtract the regular exp.value, multiply out everything and simplify: It simplifies to just   n/6 - (1/6n)  . Now normalizing to n yields: 1/6 - (1/6n^2)   -   so it's ALMOST a proportionality factor of 1/6, but smaller by 1/6n^2.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but wanted to provide another perspective. It still involves some computation.

Let $A$ and $B$ be the maximum and minimum of two die rolls $X_1, X_2$ respectively, we have
$$
\mathbb{E}[A+B] = \mathbb{E}[X_1+X_2] = 7, \quad \mathbb{E}[A-B]=\mathbb{E}[|X_1-X_2|].
$$
To compute the expected range $\mathbb{E}[A-B]$ note that among $36$ outcomes there are $2\times k$ outcomes for the range to be $6-k$. For example, for the range to be $2$, two rolls must be $(1,3), (2,4), (3,5), (4,6)$ and the factor of $2$ accounts for symmetry. Hence
$$
\mathbb{E}[A-B] = \frac{2}{36}\left(1\times 5+2\times 4+3\times 3+\cdots+5\times1\right) = \frac{35}{18},
$$
and consequently $\mathbb{E}[A] = (7+\frac{35}{18})/2=\frac{161}{36}$.