# Sum of n dice results where m lowest results are discarded

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, dice, average

I am looking for a way to calculate average result of throwing any number of any die and discarding some of the lowest ones. In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223238/what-is-the-average-of-rolling-two-dice-and-only-taking-the-value-of-the-higher?newreg=367ad4f060bf4881b6d87592be226209) question I found out how to do this for two 6-sided dices while discarding one with the lowest score but while i tried to use this for three 6-sided dices while still discarding single lowest score I failed to modify equation to my needs.

So the question stands, what is the way to calculate the "Sum of the results" of n dices with m sides while discarding x dices with lowest score where x < n and n,m != 0

Sorry for the lack of proper syntax

Comment: [This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/130025/351712) has several answers which are highly computationally efficient. However, it is well beyond introductory-level.

Comment: @HighDiceRoller can you confirm to me that changing k in accepted answer on the right function leads to discarding more dices than one?

Comment: Unfortunately not; it is the value of the lowest die. If you prefer the generating function approach, you can refer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3765873/1035142) for dropping multiple dice.

Comment: Also this. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444367/roll-dice-and-ignore-worst-results/4667966#4667966

Comment: @ThomasB. thank you very much, my question looks like a duplicate then