# What are the percent chances of rolling a number when you roll two dice and take the higher number?

Tags: probability, percentages

Say I roll two twenty-sided dice and always take the higher number rolled, and dispose of the lower number. What are the percent chances of rolling each number on the die?
I tried the equations in this question: [What is the average of rolling two dice and only taking the value of the higher dice roll?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223238/what-is-the-average-of-rolling-two-dice-and-only-taking-the-value-of-the-higher)
But for some reason I couldn't get the correct answer.

Comment: The die are numbered $\{1,\dots,20\}$?  So there are $400$ equally likely pairs.  A bit hard for direct enumeration, but still.  The only ways to get $k$ as the  maximum are to toss $\{k,j\}$ or $\{j,k\}$ with $j<k$, or to throw $\{k,k\}$.  Not that hard to count!

Comment: How many times are you planning to roll the dice? For example, if you roll them infinitely many times, then the probability is $100\%$.

Comment: @barakmanos I want to know the percentages for getting each number in one roll.

Comment: There are $20$ numbers. How can you possibly get all of them in $1$ roll of $2$ dice?????

Comment: @barakmanos I could have been clearer there. I meant I want to know the percent chances for any given number in 1-20 in one roll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is $1$ way to get a $1$, namely $(1,1)$

There are $3$ ways to get a $2$, namely $(1,2),(2,2),(2,1)$

There are $5$ ways to get a $3$, namely $(1,3),(2,3),(3,3),(3,2),(3,1)$

In general there are $2k-1$ ways to get a $k$.

The basic percentage unit is $0.25\%$, so the percentage chance to throw a $k$ is $(\frac{2k-1}{4})\%$, e.g. for $k=5$ the percentage is $1.25\%$.