# Sigma Notation to Discrete Values

Tags: summation

I was reading the top voted answer for [What is the average of rolling two dice and only taking the value of the higher dice roll?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223238/what-is-the-average-of-rolling-two-dice-and-only-taking-the-value-of-the-higher?newreg=51816bf7b082497ab1209f84e98d934b)

I ran into the following
$$\begin{align*}
&=\frac1{18}\sum_{k=1}^6k^2-\frac1{36}\sum_{k=1}^6k\\
&=\frac{6\cdot7\cdot13}{18\cdot6}-\frac{6\cdot7}{36\cdot2}\\
\end{align*}$$

I want to understand how this transformation from sigma notation to discrete values without writing out the entire series is done, what should I study?

If it's simple enough to explain feel free to just explain it in the answer, otherwise I'm happy to educate myself with Khan Academy, Brilliant.org or somewhere else.  I just don't know what to look up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$